# Updating one JavaScript object updates them all

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a script that generates x number of butterflies on a canvas, I'm using some moderately primitive function constructors so that each butterfly can be modified without affecting any other but on updating one of the sequences it updates all of them and I cannot see why at all.

Due to the sheer amount of code (over 350 lines) I've created a [JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dmackintosh88/y2QUL/17/) to be viewed (and probably frowned upon)

You can view it all [here](http://jsfiddle.net/dmackintosh88/y2QUL/17/) in full.

But since I can't post just a link to JSFiddle, here is the code for the sequence function itself.

```
function Sequence (s, f) {
    // Check we have arguments
    if (!s || !f) {
        throw new TypeError('No sequences to load');
    }

    // Instance for the onload event
    var _sq  = this;

    // Some public properties
    this.w  = 0;
    this.r  = false;
    this.st = 0;
    this.ns = 22;

    // This is the step in the sequence we're at
    this.s  = 20;

    // The step width
    this.sw = 0;

    // Create the image
    this._s = new Image;
    this._f = new Image;

    // Load listener 
    this._s.onload = function () {
        // Set our publics
        _sq.w = this.width;
        _sq.sw = _sq.w / fps;
    };

    this._s.src = s;
    this._f.src = f;

    // Return
    return this;
};
```

*[edit]*
I've updated the sequence class to basically not care about the load, it's prefetched anyway using

```
<link rel="prefetch" href="image.png" />
```

I've also updated the JSFiddle so you can see it working (there are several other updates as well) but the code is a bit unwieldy and thus I won't go into it.

Comment: Sorry, the fiddle code hung my browser (FF21). I'm not at a particular fast computer, but perhaps worth to note if this is meant for public.

Comment: It's aimed at iPads only, it seems okay on all iPads and my macbook. I've updated the link as well, linked to the wrong version.

Comment: you should 1) set the functions on the prototypes and use 'this' within those functions to avoid memory waste / use of closures 2) store the images only once in, say, a 'SequenceImage' class. 3) use requestAnimationFrame to have a smooth animation.  I see the butterflies all moving randomly, what is the issue ?

Comment: @VincentPiel I think it's that when you click on a butterfly, it's supposed to only make the ones under the cursor change color, not all of them.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm trying to get happen but it's updating all of the Sequence objects instead of just the one and I can't see why.

Comment: defining the prototype functions inside of the constructor over and over again is a bad idea. you only need to do this once. and something like `_p.load` in the Sequence constructor is even more worse, because  there you have closures that would have strange side effects. but i don't know if this is the reason for the problem, your code is really hard to read.

Comment: It has gotten increasingly difficult to update, side effect of being ill unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as already mentioned in the comment the code is hard to read.

But you problem most likely is here:

```
    for ( ; i < no_of_butterflies; i++) {
        // Create the sequence
        var s = new Sequence('http://ok5.com/blue-walking.png', 'http://ok5.com/blue-flying-2.png');

        // Listen to the load
        s.loaded = function() {
            bs.push(new Butterfly(s));
        };

        // Load the beast up
        s.load();
    }
```

the `s.loaded` callback is called when the image is loaded. so for all of you butterflies you have the same `Sequence` and out of the sequence you take the status and the image. i can't tell you why the rest of the code seems to work, i do not really have time to debug your code. My suggestion is to read about scopes and closures and do a clean rewrite, because i think there are more problems like that.

**EDIT**
A fix could be to pass the Sequence as parameter:

```
// If we have a loaded listener, fire it
if (_sq.loaded) {
    _sq.loaded(_sq);
}
```

And changing the callback to this:

```
// Listen to the load
s.loaded = function(s) {
    bs.push(new Butterfly(s));
};
```

But you have to check if is is working correct then.

Comment: Somewhat of a dramatic response, the code isn't *that* bad but I have been looking into this callback to see if that is the issue.

Comment: it is hard to read for someone who does not know the code because of  the abbreviations. and because it is hard to read, it is not easy so see bugs. my suggestion about a clean rewrite is base on this, the missunderstanding of scoping in the loop above and in the way you set your prototypes. i did not have a more detailed look on the code, but from these problems i would assume that it could be helpful to do a clean rewrite, to avoid further problems.

Comment: While I don't agree with your entire response, the underlying issue was with the callback. I moved the creation of Sequence into the butterfly constructor and now ignore the load even externally to Sequence. Your premise was correct, response though wasn't entirely constructive.